# How to write “not a subset” of a set?

Tags: math-mode

How to write A is not a subset of B in LaTeX? I can write `$A\nsubseteq B$`, but I want to remove the equality sign. Please help.

Comment: You want to say A is properly contained in B right? Then "\subset" should work.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar Probably you can undelete your answer but I think the OP wanted something like `$A \not\subset B$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

As @karlkoeller mentions in a comment, `$A \not\subset B$` should do the job.

[image]